# Kotlin указатели

Tags: kotlin

Могу ли я сделать указатель на объект в List, чтобы даже при сортировке, изменении List, по ссылке я мог получить изначально указанный объект?

Answer (score 1):

```
val list = mutableListOf("One", "Two", "Three")
val str = list[0]
list[0] = "Zero"

println(list) //[Zero, Two, Three]
println(str)  //One
```

Элементарно :)

Comment: Я имел ввиду не копию объекта, а ссылку на него. Т.е в данном примере, я бы хотел получить str "Zero"

Comment: Простите, а как понимать "получить изначально указанный объект"?

Comment: Я хочу получить изначально указанный объект, но что-то внутри объекта может измениться. Например у меня будет не строка, а какой-то класс. У меня все что угодно может внутри объекта поменяться и сам объект может куда угодно переместиться, но созданный мною указатель всеравно указывает на этот объект. А сейчас я создал просто копию

Comment: Вы пытаетесь какие-то паттерны из С или С++ сюда притянуть. Это как-то все звучит странно для JVM языка.

Comment: Поэтому я и задал вопрос могу ли я это сделать:)

Comment: "объект может куда угодно переместиться" -- это для JVM уже другой обьект. Задайте лучше новый вопрос с кодом, который должен решать что вы хотите, посмотрим.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В kotlin для этого есть прекрасный метод - `withIndex()`

Достаточно применить его на коллекции и каждый её элемент станет `IndexedValue`. У него есть `.value` и `.index`, так что теперь как бы вы не перемещали этот объект, вы всегда сможете найти его по первоначальному индексу.

Код:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var list = listOf("One", "Two", "Zero").withIndex()
    list = list.reversed()
    println(list.find { it.index == 0 })
}
```

Вывод:

```kotlin
IndexedValue(index=0, value=One)
```

После изменения списка всё ещё с лёгкостью можно найти элемент, который изначально имел индекс `[0]`, полагаю, что данное решение является тем самым указателем, о котором вы спрашивали.